# Are the timestamps of verbose JVM garbage collection logs the beginning or end of the collection?

Tags: java, logging, garbage-collection, jvm

Are the timestamps of verbose JVM garbage collection logs the beginning or end of the collection?

```
2016-08-09T21:04:19.756-0400: 224890.317: [GC Desired survivor size 167510016 bytes, new threshold 15 (max 15) [PSYoungGen: 1179767K->111478K(1231104K)] 3952529K->2891847K(4027328K), 0.2618080 secs] [Times: user=1.02 sys=0.00, real=0.26 secs] 
2016-08-09T21:04:20.018-0400: 224890.579: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 111478K->0K(1231104K)] [ParOldGen: 2780369K->2408093K(2796224K)] 2891847K->2408093K(4027328K) [PSPermGen: 530364K->530261K(530880K)], 7.9147990 secs] [Times: user=26.41 sys=0.02, real=7.91 secs]
```

Did the first collection start at 2016-08-09T21:04:19.756-0400 and end .26 seconds later or did it start .26 seconds prior to the timestamp?

Comment: you can turn on more verbose logging than that if you actually need to know the start and end times of various GC phases or safepoints surrounding the GC.

Comment: According to [this source](https://plumbr.eu/blog/garbage-collection/understanding-garbage-collection-logs) it represents the time the GC event started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timestamps denote the beginning of garbage collection phase.

There are multiple places in HotSpot source code where timestamps are printed, depending on GC algorithm and `PrintGCDetails` option, but in all cases this is done at the very beginning of GC: [genCollectedHeap.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/1f6b58e0bd06/src/share/vm/memory/genCollectedHeap.cpp#l396), [defNewGeneration.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/1f6b58e0bd06/src/share/vm/memory/defNewGeneration.cpp#l588), [parNewGeneration.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/1f6b58e0bd06/src/share/vm/gc_implementation/parNew/parNewGeneration.cpp#l961), [g1CollectedHeap.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/1f6b58e0bd06/src/share/vm/gc_implementation/g1/g1CollectedHeap.cpp#l1292), etc.